# Relational & Object-Oriented Database which one is better, will be suppressed?

Tags: database, rdbms, object-oriented-database

I wonder if RDBMS or OODBMS will be suppressed in near future?

Today I read quite a few articles about differences in both of them and most of the articles seem to favor OODBMS. Does that mean that RDBMS will be suppressed by, not yet well developed, OODBMS? If not, what makes you think so?

Comment: try to quickly find info in a blob.  try to quickly find info in 50 blobs.  try to quickly find info in 500,000 blobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the new world of information is all about BLOBs.

No, it isn't.  BLOBs are useful for certain things, but they don't replace or make obsolete more structured databases or the appropriate use of data types.

The relational model is very good at solving a certain class of data organization problem.  Non-relational models solve some different problems, but that doesn't make the relational model obsolete.

There are other non-relational database architectures emerging all the time.  And this has been going on since the relational model was first published.

We can use OODBMS, key-value stores, MapReduce frameworks, semantic web, etc., without detracting from RDBMS.  **There is no zero-sum game.**

Answer (score 5):

what is better pickup truck or sedan?

usage can overlap but both have a specialized purpose.  When used for their intended task, they work better than the other used incorrectly:

- **bad**: sofa sticking out of the sedan's window on moving day!
- **good**: sofa in the back of the pickup truck on moving day.
- **bad**: carpool people riding in the back of the pickup truck down the car pool lane!
- **good**: people sitting in the seats of the sedan in the car pool lane.

Answer (score 1):

And no one is going to rewrite the millions (maybe billions now that I think of it) of business critical relational databases out there anytime soon to be OODBMS.

Comment: True - any more than the COBOL programs are all about to be rewritten in ... well, choose your poison.  But that doesn't mean that COBOL is necessarily the place to be.